# Change drawable color with Material Design Android library

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I have created a vector asset in my `drawable` folder and changed its color to `#155724` in its `xml` file. But whenever I try to add this `drawable` to my `button`, my drawable always picks `primaryColor` which I have declared in my `colors.xml` file. Please note that I am using `material-design` library.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#155724"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#155724"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z" />
</vector>
```

This is how I am adding my drawable in my button:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:textColor="#155724"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_check_circle_24"
                app:strokeColor="#155724" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to the button as default attribute are colorPrimary
[image]

```
app:iconTint="@color/yourColor"
```